# Is there a way to generalize this TrieMap code?

Tags: haskell

Below is a simple Haskell program which computes equalities on trees:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Maybe

data Tree = Leaf | Node Tree Tree

eqTree :: Tree -> Tree -> Maybe ()
eqTree Leaf         Leaf         = return ()
eqTree (Node l1 r1) (Node l2 r2) = eqTree l1 l2 >> eqTree r1 r2
eqTree _ _ = empty
```

Suppose you have an association list of trees `[(Tree, a)]`, and you'd like to find the entry for a given tree. (One can think of this as a simplified version of the type class instance lookup problem.) Naively, we would have to do O(n*s) work, where n is the number of trees, and s is the size of each tree.

We can do better if we use a trie map to represent our association list:

```
(>.>) = flip (.)

data TreeMap a
    = TreeMap {
        tm_leaf :: Maybe a,
        tm_node :: TreeMap (TreeMap a)
      }

lookupTreeMap :: Tree -> TreeMap a -> Maybe a
lookupTreeMap Leaf       = tm_leaf
lookupTreeMap (Node l r) = tm_node >.> lookupTreeMap l >=> lookupTreeMap r
```

Our lookup now only takes O(s). This algorithm is a strict generalization of the previous one, since we can test for equality by creating a singleton `TreeMap ()` and then seeing if we get back `Just ()`. But for practical reasons, we'd prefer not to do this, since it involves building up a TreeMap and then immediately tearing it down.

Is there a way to generalize the two pieces of code above into a new function that can operate on both `Tree` and `TreeMap`? There seems to be some similarity in how the code is structured, but it is not obvious how to abstract the differences away.

Comment: May want to also ask this on the code review stack exchange :)

Comment: I'm not seeing how `TreeMap a` is equivalent to `[(Tree, a)]`.

Comment: Your `>.>` operator is equivalent to `>>>` operator from Control.Arrow module included in base package.

Comment: @Cirdec They're not isomorphic. OP is saying that `TreeMap` is a different, better data structure for the purpose of mapping `Tree`s to `a`s.

Comment: I'd like to clarify something about the question: is the goal here to avoid writing `eqTree` and `lookupTreeMap` entirely in favor of writing a single, more general function, or is the goal to write a new function which can use the more efficient of the two (but may assume they already exist as subroutines)?

Comment: Former. In the real world code, it's not eqTree but an entire unification algorithm, and you kind of want to avoid writing it twice.

Comment: @EdwardZ.Yang Which parts of the "entire unification algorithm" are going to vary? The pattern matches in the first arguments of `eqTree` and `lookupTreeMap`? The operations performed on the right sides of the different cases? The operations performed in each direction for a single case? The last one is probably the most important to know in order to answer this question.

Comment: Well, let's try to solve it for the simple case first, since it's a degenerate case of unification where there are no unification variables. In real unification, you also need a state monad tracking the current unifying substitution and handling for variables.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit**: I remembered a very helpful fact about logarithms and derivatives which I discovered whilst disgustingly hung over on a friend's sofa. Sadly, that friend (the late great Kostas Tourlas) is no longer with us, but I commemorate him by being disgustingly hung over on a different friend's sofa.

Let's remind ourselves about tries. (Lots of my mates were working on these structures in the early noughties: Ralf Hinze, Thorsten Altenkirch and Peter Hancock spring instantly to mind in that regard.) What's really going on is that we're computing the exponential of a type `t`, remembering that `t -> x` is a way of writing `x` ^ `t`.

That is, we expect to equip a type `t` with a functor `Expo t` such that `Expo t x` represents `t -> x`. We should further expect `Expo t` to be applicative (zippily). **Edit:** Hancock calls such functors "Naperian", because they have logarithms, and they're applicative in the same way as functions, with `pure` being the K combinator and `<*>` being S. It is immediate that `Expo t ()` must be isomorphic with `()`, with `const (pure ())` and `const ()` doing the (not much) work.

```
class Applicative (Expo t) => EXPO t where
  type Expo t :: * -> *
  appl  :: Expo t x -> (t -> x)       -- trie lookup
  abst  :: (t -> x) -> Expo t x       -- trie construction
```

Another way of putting it is that `t` is the *logarithm* of `Expo t`.

(I nearly forgot: fans of calculus should check that `t` is isomorphic to `∂ (Expo t) ()`. This isomorphism might actually be rather useful. **Edit:** it's extremely useful, and we shall add it to `EXPO` later.)

We'll need some functor kit stuff. The identity functor is zippiy applicative...

```
data I     ::                         (* -> *) where
  I   :: x -> I x
  deriving (Show, Eq, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

instance Applicative I where
  pure x = I x
  I f <*> I s = I (f s)
```

...and its logarithm is the unit type

```
instance EXPO () where
  type Expo () = I
  appl (I x) () = x
  abst f        = I (f ())
```

Products of zippy applicatives are zippily applicative...

```
data (:*:) :: (* -> *) -> (* -> *) -> (* -> *) where
  (:*:) :: f x -> g x -> (f :*: g) x
  deriving (Show, Eq, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

instance (Applicative p, Applicative q) => Applicative (p :*: q) where
  pure x = pure x :*: pure x
  (pf :*: qf) <*> (ps :*: qs) = (pf <*> ps) :*: (qf <*> qs)
```

...and their logarithms are sums.

```
instance (EXPO s, EXPO t) => EXPO (Either s t) where
  type Expo (Either s t) = Expo s :*: Expo t
  appl (sf :*: tf) (Left s)  = appl sf s
  appl (sf :*: tf) (Right t) = appl tf t
  abst f = abst (f . Left) :*: abst (f . Right)
```

Compositions of zippy applicatives are zippily applicative...

```
data (:<:) :: (* -> *) -> (* -> *) -> (* -> *) where
  C :: f (g x) -> (f :<: g) x
  deriving (Show, Eq, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

instance (Applicative p, Applicative q) => Applicative (p :<: q) where
  pure x          = C (pure (pure x))
  C pqf <*> C pqs = C (pure (<*>) <*> pqf <*> pqs)
```

and their logarithms are products.

```
instance (EXPO s, EXPO t) => EXPO (s, t) where
  type Expo (s, t) = Expo s :<: Expo t
  appl (C stf) (s, t) = appl (appl stf s) t
  abst f = C (abst $ \ s -> abst $ \ t -> f (s, t))
```

If we switch on enough stuff, we may now write

```
newtype Tree    = Tree (Either () (Tree, Tree))
  deriving (Show, Eq)
pattern Leaf     = Tree (Left ())
pattern Node l r = Tree (Right (l, r))

newtype ExpoTree x = ExpoTree (Expo (Either () (Tree, Tree)) x)
  deriving (Show, Eq, Functor, Applicative)

instance EXPO Tree where
  type Expo Tree = ExpoTree
  appl (ExpoTree f) (Tree t) = appl f t
  abst f = ExpoTree (abst (f . Tree))
```

The `TreeMap a` type in the question, being

```
data TreeMap a
    = TreeMap {
        tm_leaf :: Maybe a,
        tm_node :: TreeMap (TreeMap a)
      }
```

is exactly `Expo Tree (Maybe a)`, with `lookupTreeMap` being `flip appl`.

Now, given that `Tree` and `Tree -> x` are rather different things, it strikes me as odd to want code to work "on both". The tree equality test is a special case of the lookup only in that the tree equality test is any old function which acts on a tree. There is a coincidence coincidence, however: to test equality, we must turn each tree into own self-recognizer. **Edit:** that's exactly what the log-diff iso 
does.

The structure which gives rise to an equality test is some notion of *matching*. Like this:

```
class Matching a b where
  type Matched a b :: *
  matched :: Matched a b -> (a, b)
  match   :: a -> b -> Maybe (Matched a b)
```

That is, we expect `Matched a b` to represent somehow a pair of an `a` and a `b` which match. We should be able to extract the pair (forgetting that they match), and we should be able to take any pair and try to match them.

Unsurprisingly, we can do this for the unit type, quite successfully.

```
instance Matching () () where
  type Matched () () = ()
  matched () = ((), ())
  match () () = Just ()
```

For products, we work componentwise, with component mismatch being the only danger.

```
instance (Matching s s', Matching t t') => Matching (s, t) (s', t') where
  type Matched (s, t) (s', t') = (Matched s s', Matched t t')
  matched (ss', tt') = ((s, t), (s', t')) where
    (s, s') = matched ss'
    (t, t') = matched tt'
  match (s, t) (s', t') = (,) <$> match s s' <*> match t t'
```

Sums offer some chance of mismatch.

```
instance (Matching s s', Matching t t') =>
    Matching (Either s t) (Either s' t') where
  type Matched (Either s t) (Either s' t')
    = Either (Matched s s') (Matched t t')
  matched (Left  ss') = (Left s,  Left s')  where (s, s') = matched ss'
  matched (Right tt') = (Right t, Right t') where (t, t') = matched tt'
  match (Left s)  (Left s')  = Left  <$> match s s'
  match (Right t) (Right t') = Right <$> match t t'
  match _         _          = Nothing
```

Amusingly, we can obtain an equality test for trees now as easily as

```
instance Matching Tree Tree where
  type Matched Tree Tree = Tree
  matched t = (t, t)
  match (Tree t1) (Tree t2) = Tree <$> match t1 t2
```

(Incidentally, the `Functor` subclass that captures a notion of matching, being

```
class HalfZippable f where  -- "half zip" comes from Roland Backhouse
  halfZip :: (f a, f b) -> Maybe (f (a, b))
```

is sadly neglected. Morally, for each such `f`, we should have

```
Matched (f a) (f b) = f (Matched a b)
```

A fun exercise is to show that if `(Traversable f, HalfZippable f)`, then the free monad on `f` has a first-order unification algorithm.)

I suppose we can build "singleton association lists" like this:

```
mapOne :: forall a. (Tree, a) -> Expo Tree (Maybe a)
mapOne (t, a) = abst f where
  f :: Tree -> Maybe a
  f u = pure a <* match t u
```

And we could try combining them with this gadget, exploiting the zippiness of all the `Expo t`s...

```
instance Monoid x => Monoid (ExpoTree x) where
  mempty = pure mempty
  mappend t u = mappend <$> t <*> u
```

...but, yet again, the utter stupidity of the `Monoid` instance for `Maybe x` continues to frustrate clean design.

We can at least manage

```
instance Alternative m => Alternative (ExpoTree :<: m) where
  empty = C (pure empty)
  C f <|> C g = C ((<|>) <$> f <*> g)
```

An amusing exercise is to fuse `abst` with `match`, and perhaps that's what the question is really driving at. Let's refactor `Matching`.

```
class EXPO b => Matching a b where
  type Matched a b :: *
  matched :: Matched a b -> (a, b)
  match'  :: a -> Proxy b -> Expo b (Maybe (Matched a b))

data Proxy x = Poxy  -- I'm not on GHC 8 yet, and Simon needs a hand here
```

For `()`, what's new is

```
instance Matching () () where
  -- skip old stuff
  match' () (Poxy :: Proxy ()) = I (Just ())
```

For sums, we need to tag successful matches, and fill in the unsuccessful parts with a magnificently Glaswegian `pure Nothing`.

```
instance (Matching s s', Matching t t') =>
    Matching (Either s t) (Either s' t') where
  -- skip old stuff
  match' (Left s) (Poxy :: Proxy (Either s' t')) =
    ((Left <$>) <$> match' s (Poxy :: Proxy s')) :*: pure Nothing
  match' (Right t) (Poxy :: Proxy (Either s' t')) =
    pure Nothing :*: ((Right <$>) <$> match' t (Poxy :: Proxy t'))
```

For pairs, we need to build matching in sequence, dropping out early if the
first component fails.

```
instance (Matching s s', Matching t t') => Matching (s, t) (s', t') where
  -- skip old stuff
  match' (s, t) (Poxy :: Proxy (s', t'))
    = C (more <$> match' s (Poxy :: Proxy s')) where
    more Nothing  = pure Nothing
    more (Just s) = ((,) s <$>) <$> match' t (Poxy :: Proxy t')
```

So we can see that there is a connection between a constructor and the trie for its matcher.

Homework: fuse `abst` with `match'`, effectively tabulating the entire process.

**Edit:** writing `match'`, we parked each sub-matcher in the position of the trie corresponding to the sub-structure. And when you think of things in particular positions, you should think of zippers and differential calculus. Let me remind you.

We'll need functorial constants and coproducts to manage choice of "where the hole is".

```
data K     :: * ->                    (* -> *) where
  K :: a -> K a x
  deriving (Show, Eq, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

data (:+:) :: (* -> *) -> (* -> *) -> (* -> *) where
  Inl :: f x -> (f :+: g) x
  Inr :: g x -> (f :+: g) x
  deriving (Show, Eq, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)
```

And now we may define

```
class (Functor f, Functor (D f)) => Differentiable f where
  type D f :: (* -> *)
  plug :: (D f :*: I) x -> f x
  -- there should be other methods, but plug will do for now
```

The usual laws of calculus apply, with composition giving a spatial interpretation to the *chain rule*.

```
instance Differentiable (K a) where
  type D (K a) = K Void
  plug (K bad :*: I x) = K (absurd bad)

instance Differentiable I where
  type D I = K ()
  plug (K () :*: I x) = I x

instance (Differentiable f, Differentiable g) => Differentiable (f :+: g) where
  type D (f :+: g) = D f :+: D g
  plug (Inl f' :*: I x) = Inl (plug (f' :*: I x))
  plug (Inr g' :*: I x) = Inr (plug (g' :*: I x))

instance (Differentiable f, Differentiable g) => Differentiable (f :*: g) where
  type D (f :*: g) = (D f :*: g) :+: (f :*: D g)
  plug (Inl (f' :*: g) :*: I x) = plug (f' :*: I x) :*: g
  plug (Inr (f :*: g') :*: I x) = f :*: plug (g' :*: I x)

instance (Differentiable f, Differentiable g) => Differentiable (f :<: g) where
  type D (f :<: g) = (D f :<: g) :*: D g
  plug ((C f'g :*: g') :*: I x) = C (plug (f'g :*: I (plug (g' :*: I x))))
```

It will not harm us to insist that `Expo t` is differentiable, so let us extend the `EXPO` class. What's a "trie with a hole"? It's a trie which is missing the output entry for exactly one of the possible inputs. And that's the key.

```
class (Differentiable (Expo t), Applicative (Expo t)) => EXPO t where
  type Expo t :: * -> *
  appl  :: Expo t x -> t -> x
  abst  :: (t -> x) -> Expo t x
  hole  :: t -> D (Expo t) ()
  eloh  :: D (Expo t) () -> t
```

Now, `hole` and `eloh` will witness the isomorphism.

```
instance EXPO () where
  type Expo () = I
  -- skip old stuff
  hole ()     = K ()
  eloh (K ()) = ()
```

The unit case wasn't very exciting, but the sum case begins to show structure:

```
instance (EXPO s, EXPO t) => EXPO (Either s t) where
  type Expo (Either s t) = Expo s :*: Expo t
  hole (Left s)  = Inl (hole s  :*: pure ())
  hole (Right t) = Inr (pure () :*: hole t)
  eloh (Inl (f' :*: _)) = Left (eloh f')
  eloh (Inr (_ :*: g')) = Right (eloh g')
```

See? A `Left` is mapped to a trie with a hole on the left; a `Right` is mapped to a trie with a hole on the right.

Now for products.

```
instance (EXPO s, EXPO t) => EXPO (s, t) where
  type Expo (s, t) = Expo s :<: Expo t
  hole (s, t) = C (const (pure ()) <$> hole s) :*: hole t
  eloh (C f' :*: g') = (eloh (const () <$> f'), eloh g')
```

A trie for a pair is a right trie stuffed inside a left trie, so the hole for a particular pair is found by making a hole for the right element in the particular subtrie for the left element.

For trees, we make another wrapper.

```
newtype DExpoTree x = DExpoTree (D (Expo (Either () (Tree, Tree))) x)
  deriving (Show, Eq, Functor)
```

So, how do we turn a tree into its trie recognizer? First, we grab its "everyone but me" trie, and we fill in all those outputs with `False`, then we plug in `True` for the missing entry.

```
matchMe :: EXPO t => t -> Expo t Bool
matchMe t = plug ((const False <$> hole t) :*: I True)
```

**Homework hint:** `D f :*: I` is a comonad.

Absent friends!

Comment: Excellent. I got as far as looking for the operation that turns products into sums and exponents into products; I can't believe I didn't think "logarithm".

Comment: This pattern synonym can make some of the code look nicer `pattern Matched :: Matching a a' => a -> a' -> Matched a a'; pattern Matched a a' <- (matched -> (a, a'))`

Answer (score 2):

This is a naïve solution. The class `BinaryTree` describes how both `Tree`s and `TreeMap`s are binary trees.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}

class BinaryTree t a where
    leaf :: MonadPlus m => t a -> m a
    node :: MonadPlus m => (forall r. BinaryTree t r => t r -> m r) ->
                           (forall r. BinaryTree t r => t r -> m r) ->
                           t a -> m a
```

The awkward `BinaryTree t r` constraints and the multi-parameter type class are only necessary because `Tree`s don't hold an `a` at their leaves to `return`. If your real `Tree` is richer this wrinkle will probably disappear.

`lookupTreeMap` can be written in terms of `BinaryTree` instead of in terms of `Tree` or `TreeMap`

```
lookupTreeMap' :: BinaryTree t r => Tree -> t r -> Maybe r
lookupTreeMap' Leaf = leaf
lookupTreeMap' (Node l r) = node (lookupTreeMap' l) (lookupTreeMap' r)
```

`TreeMap` has a straightforward `BinaryTree` instance.

```
instance BinaryTree TreeMap a where
    leaf = maybe empty return . tm_leaf
    node kl kr = tm_node >.> kl >=> kr
```

`Tree` can't have a `BinaryTree` instance because it has the wrong kind. That's easily fixed with a newtype:

```
newtype Tree2 a = Tree2 {unTree2 :: Tree}

tree2 :: Tree -> Tree2 ()
tree2 = Tree2
```

`Tree2` can be equiped with a `BinaryTree` instance.

```
instance BinaryTree Tree2 () where
    leaf (Tree2 Leaf) = return ()
    leaf _ = empty

    node kl kr (Tree2 (Node l r)) = kl (tree2 l) >> kr (tree2 r)
    node _ _ _ = empty
```

---

I don't think the above is a particularly elegant solution, or that it will necessarily simplify anything, unless the implementation of `lookupTreeMap` is non-trivial. As an incremental improvement, I'd recommend refactoring `Tree` into the base functor

```
data TreeF a = Leaf | Node a a

data Tree = Tree (TreeF Tree)
```

We can split the problem into matching the base functor against itself,

```
-- This looks like a genaralized version of Applicative that can fail
untreeF :: MonadPlus m => TreeF (a -> m b) -> TreeF a -> m (TreeF b)
untreeF Leaf         Leaf       = return Leaf
untreeF (Node kl kr) (Node l r) = Node <$> kl l <*> kr r
untreeF _            _          = empty
```

matching the base functor against `Tree`s,

```
untree :: MonadPlus m => TreeF (Tree -> m ()) -> Tree -> m () 
untree tf (Tree tf2) = untreeF tf tf2 >> return ()
```

and matching the base functor against `TreeMap`.

```
-- A reader for things that read from a TreeMap to avoid impredicative types.
data TMR m = TMR {runtmr :: forall r. TreeMap r -> m r}

-- This work is unavoidable. Something has to say how a TreeMap is related to Trees
untreemap :: MonadPlus m => TreeF (TMR m) -> TMR m
untreemap Leaf = TMR $ maybe empty return . tm_leaf
untreemap (Node kl kr) = TMR $ tm_node >.> runtmr kl >=> runtmr kr
```

Like in the first example, we define traversing the tree only once.

```
-- This looks suspiciously like a traversal / transform
lookupTreeMap' :: (TreeF a -> a) -> Tree -> a
lookupTreeMap' un = go
  where
    go (Tree Leaf) = un Leaf
    go (Tree (Node l r)) = un $ Node (go l) (go r)
    -- If the traversal is trivial these can be replaced by
    -- go (Tree tf) = un $ go <$> tf
```

The operations specialized for `Tree` and `TreeMap` can be obtained from the single definition of the traversal.

```
eqTree :: Tree -> Tree -> Maybe ()
eqTree = lookupTreeMap' untree

lookupTreeMap :: MonadPlus m => Tree -> TreeMap a -> m a
lookupTreeMap = runtmr . lookupTreeMap' untreemap
```

Comment: To me, `lookupTreeMap'` looks suspiciously like a catamorphism, specifically `cata` from `recursion-schemes`. In fact, I think it may even be that...