# Haskell Recursion Schemes: Traverse two structures simultaneously

Tags: algorithm, haskell, recursion, unification, recursion-schemes

I'm trying to write Robinson's unification algorithm using recursion schemes.
The unification algorithm takes two types and spits a result.
A type is a:

```
data TypeF a
    = TypeApplication a a
    | TypeVariable Name
    deriving (Read,Show,Eq,Functor,Foldable,Traversable)
type Type = Fix TypeF

unify :: Type -> Type -> Result
unify = ...
```

How can this be done elegantly using recursion schemes?

Comment: What is `Result`?

Comment: A Substitution, but that doesn't really matter.

Comment: think about your base cases - how should a `TypeVariable n` and a `TypeVariable m` unify? a `TypeVariable n` and a `TypeApplication x y`? a `TypeApplication x y` and a `TypeApplication u v`?

Comment: i) use the free monad rather than the raw fixpoint to distinguish variables from all other constructs (and to obtain a handy implementation of substitution); ii) learn about the halfZip operation (google it!); iii) note that any functor which is halfzippable and traversable induces a free monad with a Robinson unification algorithm

Comment: Since @pigworker's Google search turns up a lot of clothing, you might look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45254970/1477667

Comment: halfZip Haskell narrows it down...

Answer (score 2):

I'd just suggest currying and a hylomorphism.

```
data TypeF a
    = TypeApplication a a
    | TypeVariable Name
    deriving (Read,Show,Eq,Functor,Foldable,Traversable)
type Type = Fix TypeF

unify :: (Type, Type) -> Result
unify = hylo algebra coalgebra
    where algebra :: TypeF Result -> Result
          algebra = ...
          coalgebra :: (Type, Type) -> TypeF (Type, Type)
          coalgebra = ...
```

As an aside, I would probably with `TypeF` as follows, using the [recursion-schemes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.0.2) package.

```
import Data.Functor.Foldable.TH (makeBaseFunctor)

data Type = TypeApplication Type Type
          | TypeVariable Name

makeBaseFunctor ''Type
```

This will automatically generate exactly what you want in this case, with no need to use to `Fix`.