# Which Haskell Functors are equivalent to the Reader functor

Tags: haskell, functor, category-theory

Some Haskell functors `F a` are obviously isomorphic to `T -> a` for some type `T`, e.g.

```
data Pair a = Pair a a            -- isomorphic to Bool -> a
data Reader r a = Reader (r -> a) -- isomorphic to r -> a (duh!)
data Identity a = Identity a      -- isomorphic to () -> a
data Phantom a = Phantom          -- isomorphic to void -> a
```

(These isomorphism are only up to strictness, and considering only finite data structures.)

So in general, how can we characterize functors where this is possible?

And is the question “Which Haskell Functors are representable?” the same question?

Comment: I can follow the first examples, but I can not understand the last one for `[a]`. Can you describe that dependent type you use there?

Comment: Further, if `T,U :: *->*` are functors isomorphic to `T' -> a` and `U' -> a`, their product `F a = (T a, F a)` is isomorphic to `Either T' U' -> a`. Hence, you can craft from this many more examples. E.g. `F a = (a,a,...)` is `Either () (Either () ...) -> a`

Comment: Google "Naperian Functor": Hancock gives them that name, because the domain of the representing function is log_x (f x). By the way, [] is *not* Naperian, because the length of the list may vary. Vec n is Naperian for each n. Naperian functors are closed under constant unit (Phantom), product, exponentiation (a ->) aka Reader, identity, composition, and greatest fixpoint (Streams are Naperian as they are bound to be infinite). They also have the property that f () (aka the "shape type") is iso to (). There's a connection to the Zipper: if f () is iso to (), then log_x (f x) = D f ().

Comment: I feel out of my depth here, so I'm not sure the following helps, but [adjunctions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions) define a `Representable` type class and some instances.

Comment: @chi, oh, there is a typo there. Should be `Fin n`… and even then it’s wrong. `Σ n, (Fin n -> a)` would work, but not  `(Σ n, Fin n) -> a)` as I wrote initially.

Comment: @pigworker care to turn that into an answer? (Ideally with an explanation of the difference between “naperian“ and “representable”.)

Comment: I might get there. There is no difference between "Naperian" and "Representable". It's just a matter of a thing studied under more than one name.

Comment: Similarly (and not unrelatedly), what I called `Traversable` functors are what Girard has been calling "Normal" functors for years. It just took us a while to see that.

Comment: There is a Haskell library defining a bunch of [representable functors](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/representable-functors), courtesy Edward Kmett.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> And Noah said unto the animals "Go forth and multiply!", but the snakes said
>   "We cannot multiply, for we are adders.", so Noah took wood from the Ark and,
>   shaping it, said "I am building you a table of logs.".

Representable functors are sometimes also called "Naperian" functors (it's Peter Hancock's term: Hank's a denizen of the same part of Edinburgh as John Napier, of logarithmic fame) because when `F x ~= T -> x`, and remembering that, combinatorially, `T -> x` is "`x` to the power `T`", we see that `T` is in some sense `Log F`.

The first thing to note is that `F () ~= T -> () ~= ()`. That tells us *there is only one shape*. Functors which offer us a choice of shape cannot be Naperian, because they don't give a uniform presentation of the positions for data. That means `[]` is not Naperian, because different-length lists have positions represented by different types. However, an infinite `Stream` has positions given by the natural numbers.

Correspondingly, given any two `F` structures, their shapes are bound to match, so they have a sensible `zip`, giving us the basis for an `Applicative F` instance.

Indeed, we have

```
          a  -> p x
=====================
  (Log p, a) ->   x
```

making `p` a right adjoint, so `p` preserves all limits, hence unit and products in particular, making it a monoidal functor, not just a *lax* monoidal functor. That is, the alternative presentation of `Applicative` has operations which are isomorphisms.

```
unit  :: ()         ~= p ()
mult  :: (p x, p y) ~= p (x, y)
```

Let's have a type class for the things. I cook it a bit differently from the `Representable` class.

```
class Applicative p => Naperian p where
  type Log p
  logTable  :: p (Log p)
  project   :: p x -> Log p -> x
  tabulate  :: (Log p -> x) -> p x
  tabulate f = fmap f logTable
  -- LAW1: project logTable = id
  -- LAW2: project px <$> logTable = px
```

We have a type `Log f`, representing at least some of the positions inside an `f`; we have a `logTable`, storing in each position the representative of that position, acting like a 'map of an `f`' with placenames in each place; we have a `project` function extracting the data stored at a given position.

The first law tells us that the `logTable` is accurate for all the positions which are represented. The second law tells us that we have represented *all* the positions. We may deduce that

```
tabulate (project px)
  = {definition}
fmap (project px) logTable
  = {LAW2}
px
```

and that

```
project (tabulate f)
  = {definition}
project (fmap f logTable)
  = {free theorem for project}
f . project logTable
  = {LAW1}
f . id
  = {composition absorbs identity}
f
```

We could imagine a generic instance for `Applicative`

```
instance Naperian p => Applicative p where
  pure x    = fmap (pure x)                    logTable
  pf <$> px = fmap (project pf <*> project ps) logTable
```

which is as much as to say that `p` inherits its own K and S combinators from the usual K and S for functions.

Of course, we have

```
instance Naperian ((->) r) where
  type Log ((->) r) = r  -- log_x (x^r) = r
  logTable = id
  project = ($)
```

Now, all the limit-like constructions preserve Naperianity. `Log` maps limity things to colimity things: it *calculates* left adjoints.

We have the terminal object and products.

```
data K1       x = K1
instance Applicative K1 where
  pure x    = K1
  K1 <*> K1 = K1
instance Functor K1 where fmap = (<*>) . pure

instance Naperian K1 where
  type Log K1 = Void -- "log of 1 is 0"
  logTable = K1
  project K1 nonsense = absurd nonsense

data (p * q)  x = p x :*: q x
instance (Applicative p, Applicative q) => Applicative (p * q) where
  pure x = pure x :*: pure x
  (pf :*: qf) <*> (ps :*: qs) = (pf <*> ps) :*: (qf <*> qs)
instance (Functor p, Functor q) => Functor (p * q) where
  fmap f (px :*: qx) = fmap f px :*: fmap f qx

instance (Naperian p, Naperian q) => Naperian (p * q) where
  type Log (p * q) = Either (Log p) (Log q)  -- log (p * q) = log p + log q
  logTable = fmap Left logTable :*: fmap Right logTable
  project (px :*: qx) (Left i)  = project px i
  project (px :*: qx) (Right i) = project qx i
```

We have identity and composition.

```
data I        x = I x
instance Applicative I where
  pure x = I x
  I f <*> I s = I (f s)
instance Functor I where fmap = (<*>) . pure

instance Naperian I where
  type Log I = ()    -- log_x x = 1
  logTable = I ()
  project (I x) () = x

data (p << q) x = C (p (q x))
instance (Applicative p, Applicative q) => Applicative (p << q) where
  pure x = C (pure (pure x))
  C pqf <*> C pqs = C (pure (<*>) <*> pqf <*> pqs)
instance (Functor p, Functor q) => Functor (p << q) where
  fmap f (C pqx) = C (fmap (fmap f) pqx)

instance (Naperian p, Naperian q) => Naperian (p << q) where
  type Log (p << q) = (Log p, Log q)  -- log (q ^ log p) = log p * log q
  logTable = C (fmap (\ i -> fmap (i ,) logTable) logTable)
  project (C pqx) (i, j) = project (project pqx i) j
```

Naperian functors are closed under *greatest* fixpoints, with their logarithms being the corresponding *least* fixpoints. E.g., for streams, we have

```
log_x (Stream x)
  =
log_x (nu y. x * y)
  =
mu log_xy. log_x (x * y)
  =
mu log_xy. log_x x + log_x y
  =
mu log_xy. 1 + log_xy
  =
Nat
```

It's a bit fiddly to render that in Haskell without introducing Naperian *bifunctors* (which have two sets of positions for two sorts of things), or (better) Naperian functors on indexed types (which have indexed positions for indexed things). What's easy, though, and hopefully gives the idea, is the cofree comonad.

```
data{-codata-} CoFree p x = x :- p (CoFree p x)
  -- i.e., (I * (p << CoFree p)) x
instance Applicative p => Applicative (CoFree p) where
  pure x = x :- pure (pure x)
  (f :- pcf) <*> (s :- pcs) = f s :- (pure (<*>) <*> pcf <*> pcs)
instance Functor p => Functor (CoFree p) where
  fmap f (x :- pcx) = f x :- fmap (fmap f) pcx

instance Naperian p => Naperian (CoFree p) where
  type Log (CoFree p) = [Log p]  -- meaning finite lists only
  logTable = [] :- fmap (\ i -> fmap (i :) logTable) logTable
  project (x :- pcx) []       = x
  project (x :- pcx) (i : is) = project (project pcx i) is
```

We may take `Stream = CoFree I`, giving

```
Log Stream = [Log I] = [()] ~= Nat
```

Now, the derivative `D p` of a functor gives its type of one-hole context, telling us i) the shape of a `p`, ii) the position of the hole, iii) the data that are not in the hole. If `p` is Naperian, there is no choice of shape, so putting trivial data in the non-hole positions, we find that we just get the position of the hole.

```
D p () ~= Log p
```

More on that connection can be found in [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45254970/828361) about tries.

Anyhow, Naperian is indeed a funny local Scottish name for Representable, which are the things for which you can build a table of logs: they are the constructions characterized entirely by projection, offering no choice of 'shape'.

Comment: What is that quote(?) at the start from? If I search google for it, this post is the only result.

Comment: I have no idea where it's from. It's a very old joke I remember from my childhood.

Comment: Well, it's fantastic.  I'm gonna borrow it for situations where math jokes are appropriate.  Thank you for sharing!